# Where is the footer template file for zen cart?

Tags: php, html, zen-cart

There is some javascript just above the end tag for body and after the html tag, that I would like to edit/remove. But I can't find the footer template in zen cart.

Comment: Just for help with this in other projects you might encounter, I usually `grep` terms that I'm looking to change and use that to locate the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in these files:

includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/common/tpl_footer.php

includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/common/tpl_main_page.php